# How to trigger a useEffect from external function?

Tags: react-native, use-effect, react-native-firebase

I'm new to both Javascript and React Native and I need some help working out how I can trigger a useEffect from an external function.

My application is listening for messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with the react-native-firebase library. On receipt, a background handler writes the message to asyncstorage and then displays a notification with notifee library.

When the application is opened, it retrieves the messages from asyncstorage and renders them using FlatList. This works perfectly when the application is first opened and the list renders.

The problem is that if a message is received while the app is in the foreground, the handler correctly processes the incoming message and displays the notification, but it cannot trigger a refresh of the message list which has already been rendered.

How can I trigger a refresh/re-run of the useEffect from the foregroundMessageHandler?

This is the async function I'm using to capture the FCM message while the app is in the foreground:

*index.js*

```js
const foregroundMessageHandler = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {

  await _handleNewMessage(remoteMessage);  // Inserts FCM message into asyncstorage

  await onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);  // Displays notification

  // ...how to trigger a refresh of the useEffect from here??

});
```

And this is how I'm rendering the messages from asyncstorage in the UI:

*app.js*

```js
function HomeScreen() {

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

      // Function to retrieve historical messages from AsyncStorage
      async function _retrieveData() {
        try {
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('messages');
          if (value !== null) {

            const oldMessages = JSON.parse(value);

            setData(oldMessages);
            setLoading(false);

          } else {

            setData(false);
            setLoading(false);

          }
        } catch (error) {}
      }

      _retrieveData();  // Retrieve old messages from asyncstorage

  },[]);



function renderMessagesFlatList(data) {

  if (isLoading) {

    return (
      <ActivityIndicator />
    );

  } else if (data) {

  return (

  <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
            source={{uri:item.icon}}
          />
            <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 5 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#000000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.sender}</Text>
            <Text>{timeSince(item.time)} ago</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <Text style={{ paddingTop: 4 }}>{item.body}</Text>
          <Divider style={{ backgroundColor: '#e7e5e5', height: 2, marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5 }} />
          </>
        )}
    />
  );

  } else {

    return (
    <Text>No notifications to display</Text>
    );

  };

};
```

---

**Update:** Using the code below I've managed to refresh the FlatList component when a message is received. But it seems every time the useEffect fires it creates another foreground listener which results in duplicate notifications for subsequent messages. I need to work out how to stop these duplicated foreground listeners from being created.

```js
function HomeScreen() {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [refreshPage, setRefreshPage] = useState(false);

useEffect(async () => {

  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('messages35');

  // ...functions to retrieve and sort historical messages into array "sortedInput"

  setData(sortedInput);  // setState to provide initial data for FlatList component

  };

  const unsubscribeOnMessage = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {

    // Function to process new message and insert into local storage
    await _handleNewMessage(remoteMessage);

    // Display notification to user
    onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);

    // Trigger refresh of FlatList component with setState
    setRefreshPage(Math.random() * 100);

  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribeOnMessage();
  };

}, [refreshPage]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple solutions for your problem, but here's how I would prefer to solve it.

You can add another `messaging().onMessage` listener to your `HomeScreen` component and whenever a new message is received, you simply refresh your list by retrieving the data again:

```js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

function HomeScreen() {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to retrieve historical messages from AsyncStorage
    async function _retrieveData() {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('messages');
        if (value !== null) {
          const oldMessages = JSON.parse(value);

          setData(oldMessages);
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          setData(false);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {}
    }

    _retrieveData(); // Retrieve old messages from asyncstorage

    // Foreground push notifications listener
    const unsubscribeOnMessage = messaging().onMessage(() => {
      // Whenever a new push notification is received, call the _retrieveData function again
      _retrieveData();
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribeOnMessage();
    };
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

1. You can leave the `foregroundMessageHandler` out of your `HomeScreen` component (your initial code). Having multiple `messaging.onMessage` listeners is valid.
2. Instead of having `const [refreshPage, setRefreshPage] = useState(false);` you can just use `setData` in your `messaging.onMessage` listener in `HomeScreen` component. So the solution could be something like this:

*index.js*

```js
const foregroundMessageHandler = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {

  await _handleNewMessage(remoteMessage);  // Inserts FCM message into asyncstorage

  await onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);  // Displays notification

  // ...how to trigger a refresh of the useEffect from here??

});
```

*app.js*

```js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

function HomeScreen() {
  // ...
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... Other code
   
    const unsubscribeOnMessage = messaging().onMessage((remoteMessage) => {
      // use setData to update your data for FlatList. It could be used to just append the new message to the current data
      setData((data) => [...data, remoteMessage]);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribeOnMessage();
    };
    // There shouldn't be any dependencies here
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Great solution, and I'm kicking myself that I didn't think of doing it that way!

Comment: Hi @kapobajza, unfortunately it seems that moving messaging().onMessage into the HomeScreen component results in it firing multiple times. The exact same code outside of HomeScreen fires only once.

Comment: do you have any dependencies in your `useEffect` dependency array? `useEffect(() => { //... }, [dependencies]);`

Comment: I think the problem is that every time an FCM message is received and the useEffect fires it ends up creating a second foreground listener which results in duplicate notifications of subsequent messages. I don't think the unsubscribeOnMessage(); is removing the existing foreground listener.

Comment: Are you maybe calling `await onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);` inside of the `messaging().onMessage` callback on the `HomeScreen`?

Comment: I'm calling ```await _handleNewMessage(remoteMessage);``` and ```onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);``` within the ```messaging().onMessage``` callback on the ```HomeScreen``` (added code to original question), but even if I comment out those lines I still get duplicate FCM message callbacks. They double each time, i.e. 1 FCM message callback on the first message receipt, then 2 callbacks for the next message, 4 callbacks for the next, etc. Which makes me think extra ```messaging().onMessage``` foreground listeners are being created on each useEffect trigger.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Extra foreground listeners are being created on each `useEffect` trigger. Upon seeing your code, I am wondering why do you have `refreshPage` as a dependency in the `useEffect`? `useEffect(() => { //... }, [refreshPage] //Here);`

Comment: And on another note: why do you have `const [refreshPage, setRefreshPage] = useState(false);` at all? I know you're using them to refresh the data in your `FlatList`, but couldn't you just get the data in `messaging().onMessage` and then call `setData` to set the new data? I'll update my answer so that you can see what exactly I mean.